# Can you override certain action of an HTML element with given class via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-blockui

After page load I set that all anchors should block screen using the plugin [jquery-blockui](/questions/tagged/jquery-blockui) so as to prevent multiple clicks from impatient user and avoiding unnecessary multiple requests to the server.

```
$("a").on("click", $.blockUI);
```

I'm also using the [jquery ui multiselect widget](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget) and this widget uses anchors to check all options, uncheck all options, or close itself. Unfortunatelly, these anchors also fires my blockUI event. I tried to prevent the event from firing using the code below:

```
$("a.ui-multiselect-none, a.ui-multiselect-all, a.ui-multiselect-close").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

In other words, I tried to stop the default event of the anchors marked with the widget classes, but that did not work. What actually worked was what I used below:

```
$("a.ui-multiselect-none, a.ui-multiselect-all, a.ui-multiselect-close").on("click", $.unblockUI);
```

But this solution gives an effect on the screen as if it is flashing. Is there any way to make these links simply do not trigger the blockUI differently from every other anchors being an UX exception in the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you never want those objects to trigger the `blockui` call, don't place the event listener on them in the first place. Use jQuery's `:not` selector:

```
$("a:not(.ui-multiselect-none, .ui-multiselect-all, .ui-multiselect-close)").on("click", $.blockUI);
```

Comment: I accepted your answer because that what's I was looking for, I never wanted to bind the click event in the anchors that have these classes, but I did find a great tip to use the second part of the Andrei's answer to prevent later bindings.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two steps. First, remove all handlers from the `click` event:

```
$("a.ui-multiselect-none, a.ui-multiselect-all, a.ui-multiselect-close").off('click');
```

Then, optinally, assign your own handler to prevent later bindings

```
$("a.ui-multiselect-none, a.ui-multiselect-all, a.ui-multiselect-close").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Your answer worked just great but I was looking for not binding at all the click event in the anchors with these classes because of performance. It's better not to bind the click event than bind it and then remove it, still, the second part of your answer is great and I +1 your answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

1) Create a new target for blockUI

```
    $("a").on("click", $.blockUI); // Change "a" to something else like "a.target"
```

2) Change `a.ui-multiselect-none, a.ui-multiselect-all, a.ui-multiselect-close` to perform the same functionality without the need of being anchortags.

Comment: I would have to look for all the anchors in the system to do it or change the widget code, which is not developed by me.